# In spite of Firebase connected to Android Studio, the app is unable to connect to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I've made a project *Firebase Project1* in Android studio and a project in Firebase with the same name. Android studio has the file which connects it to Firebase and it has all the appropriate dependencies too:
[The Firebase file is present in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90OSg.png)

And the Firebase console is also showing that my app is connected to it.

[Firebase console shows app is connected to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xckWX.png)

[This is the url for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOD1s.png)

Despite everything seems right, my app is not connected to Firebase console. I'm unable to read/write to/from the database, I'm unable to receive notifications, I'm able to authenticate, etc.
What is the problem here? How should I solve this?

Comment: Show your code and your logs showing the error

Comment: Please provide your build.gradle file, first. Then help us with the error you got. You could also provide the code you implemented to try to access your database...